# If $f\ge0$ is integrable then $\log(1+\frac1n f)$ is integrable.

Tags: analysis

I'm really lost and don't know where to start in this exercise:

We have: $(\Omega ,A,\mu )$ a measure - space
Let $f: \Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty  )$ be an integrable function.
Show that
$g_n(x)= \log(1 + \frac{1}{n}f(x))$
are also integrable

Maybe someone can help me or give a hint how to start ?

Comment: I assume that $a>0$ and $n>0$ (probably $n\in\mathbb{N}$). Do you know some statement on the composition of an integrable function with a continuous function?

Comment: What's $\Omega$?

Comment: oh sorry a should be 1 , it is a typing error i'm sorry !!, and yes I think n>0 , but there is nothing written about it so i assume it should be like that. And we also have $(\Omega ,A,\mu )$ a measure-space

Comment: Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true [...], it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts.  – From [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969).

Comment: Hint : $\log$ is concave

Comment: @cucurbita There is no theorem which says that the composition of an integrable function with a continuous one is integrable.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy There is. Assuming that the composition makes sense, if $g$ is continuous and $f$ is integrable, then $g \circ f$ is integrable. (That's not true for the other order of composition, though, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/q/20045 .) However, an application of that result depends on the domains, so my hint wasn't really useful in the present case. The accepted answer by MotylaNogaTomkaMazura is far more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$0\leq g_n (x) =\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n } f(x) \right) =\frac{1}{\ln 10}\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{n } f(x) \right)\leq \frac{f(x)}{n\ln 10}$$
hence $$0\leq \int_{\Omega } g_n (x) \mu (dx) \leq \frac{1}{n\ln 10} \int_{\Omega } f(x) \mu (dx)<\infty$$
So $g_n$ is integrable.